# subscribe does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<Profile>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

so i'm following this tutorial on udemy. The application has a profile page where you can see the user's name and stuff.

In my provider I do:

```
profileObject: AngularFireObject 
constructor(private database: 
AngularFireDatabase ) { }

async saveProfile(user: User, profile: Profile) { 
   this.profileObject= this.database.object(/profiles/${user.uid}); 
   try { 
      this.profileObject.set(profile); 
      return true 
   } catch (e) { 
      console.error(e); 
      return false; 
   } 
}
```

And in my profile view component i go:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
  this.data.getProfile(user).subscribe((profile: Profile) => {
    this.userProfile = profile;
  })
})
```

But i get error subscribe does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject.
Any workaround?

Comment: you are calling `getProfile` but you have shown the code for `saveProfile`.. You need to provide the correct code